# How to fill an HTML Form with (a lot) of records from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, input

I've a HTML form with approx. 120 input text fields.

Then i've a PHP page with the same form where i've this code to show the value get from database.

```
<input type="text" id="field_1" name="field_1" value="<?php echo $myvalue1; ?>" />
```

Is there a way to retrieve data from database and fill the input text value for each field or doing it in a better way than specify more than 120 variables?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a loop to achieve the desired result. But do you mind to add why you are aiming to have 120 input fields for a single form ?

Comment: Apart from better UI design, consider using pagination and partially loaded pages.

Comment: You could use a loop to correspond each input to the matching field. But personally, i'd be very interested to see what kind of form needs 120 inputs.

Comment: Wait, what? I must've misunderstood! You are actually defining $myvalue1 ... $myvalue120?

Comment: it is a form used on my own business company. a single page is still good for me and for what i will do with this form. :)

Comment: @Zanathel no, at the moment i'm waiting a good suggestion from stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick in PHP. You can name your inputs using "[]" operator. like this:

```
<input type="text" id="field_1" name="field[]" value="<?php echo $myvalue1; ?>" />
```

As the result it will be treated as an array in the corresponding REQUEST array (POST or GET, depends of HTTP method for you form).
To fill the inputs, simply use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can always store the results in an array, then loop through that.

```
$q = mysql_query ( ... );
for ($i = 1; $r = mysql_fetch_row ($q); ++$i)
  printf ('<input tyle="text" id="field_%s" name="field_%s" value="%s"/>', $i, $i, $r[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your results from the query and generate textboxs

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT column FROM table"; 

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) { 
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
            echo "<input type='text' name='field[]' value='". $obj->column ."'> <br>"; // Here is the where you put your textbox in loop

        } 
    } 
    $result->close();
?>
```